# IIS7 URL Rewrite Regular Expression

Tags: regex, iis-7

I am trying to set up IIS7 so the a URL with the pattern:

www.test.com/docs/ADocument.pdf

will get redirected to the URL

www.test.com/1.0/docs/ADocument.pdf

I am having trouble with the regular expression.  The pattern should work with any page at the end of the url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite this...

```
^(docs/.*)$
```

to this...

```
1.0/{R:1}
```

Comment: Thanks, regex is my kryptonite!